# Laravel composite primary key eloquent problem

Tags: php, laravel

I have favorite table.

```
        Schema::create('favorites', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('escort_id');
            $table->foreign('escort_id')->references('id')->on('escorts');

            $table->primary(['user_id', 'escort_id']);

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

And I want to get user's favorite escorts. So I wrote this code in User.php

```
    public function favorites()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Favorite::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

I tested it on tinker and it returns below.

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
```

Is there a package or something else that can solve this??

I haven't been able to resolve it for several hours.

Answer (score 1):

so it seems like you are getting HasMany instance cause you are calling favorites() as a function, but you have to call it as a property

```php
$user = Auth::user();
$favorites = $user->favorites;
```

As for the user's favorite escorts

if u have a relation like this for it in the Favorite model

```php
public function escort()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Escort::class, 'escort_id', 'id');
}
```

then

```php
$user = Auth::user(); // replace with however you get the authenticated user
$favorites = $user->favorites;
$escorts = [];
foreach ($favorites as $favorite) {
    $escorts[] = $favorite->escort;
}
```